# ClientRpc-function Gets Called Twice

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

I don't think I understand Unity Networking correctly, thus this question.

When my player dies, I call the script CmdSetScore inside a die()-function and then call it through the server and then back to all the clients:

```
public void Die() {
    CmdSetScore(playerID, 1);
}
[Command]
public void CmdSetScore(string _playerID, int _score) {
    Player _player = GameManager.GetPlayer(_playerID);
    _player.RpcSetScore(_score);
}
[ClientRpc]
public void RpcSetScore(int _score) {
    if (!isLocalPlayer) {
        return;
    }
    score += _score;
    [...]
```

The problem is that the RpcSetScore is being called twice.
My thesis was that because I had two players in the game, it was called twice but with three players, it is still called twice.

It only happens on client side. When dying on server side, it only gets called once.

How can I call function only once?

Comment: How is Die() being called? I don't really see any issue with this code that would cause it to get called twice.

Comment: Just a guess, but do you maybe call Die() on the server version of the object and on the client version? I've done that before.